# SDL2 not being built on VS code

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, linker-errors, sdl-2

I wanted to make a game using the SDL2 library on **macOS**. I have followed the installation instructions and have added the SDL2.framework directory to /Library/Frameworks. But, I have not been able to build my code using VS code and here is the code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    cout << "not working" << endl;
  else
    cout << "working" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and this is the error that I am getting while building it:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F /Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in test-f9f99c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Here is my tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "shell: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2",
                "-I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/Headers",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
    ]
}
```

I have gone through multiple answers to similar questions but am not able to get around this problem.

The strange thing about this problem is that the code is running fine on terminal.
Here is the command : `g++ test.cpp -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/Headers -framework SDL2 -F/Library/Frameworks -o test && "/Users/shrishshankar/Desktop/Projects/Space_Invaders/"test`
(the file's name is test.cpp)

Comment: I think your problem is here: `"-F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2",` I think you need to separate this into 2 arguments instead of 1. `"-F/Library/Frameworks", "-framework SDL2",`

Comment: @drescherjm I tried, but then I get this, error: unknown argument: '-framework SDL2'

Comment: @drescherjm Probably `-framework SDL2` should be separate too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks a lot! it's working now. I've been at this for hours and finally it's fixed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat at first I did not understand your comment but I do now.. "-framework", "SDL",

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Could you please explain why was that separation necessary?

Comment: It appears the IDE quotes the individual argument so `"-F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2",` means use the folder named `/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2` as part of the  -F instead of splitting this into 3 separate arguments by space

Answer (score 0):

For installing SDL2 or other libraries on Visual Code. Follow the next steps.

First, be sure your workspace has a structure like this.

```
├── bin
├── include
├── lib
├── Makefile
└── src
```

Be sure you paste the respective files on *include* and *lib*.

If you install SDL2 with brew, you must have copied the content of:

`/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.5/include/` on `include`

and

`/usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.5/lib/` on `lib`

Next, create a Makefile with the code below and add the respective libraries.

```sh
CXX       := g++
CXX_FLAGS := -std=c++2a -ggdb

BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE_PATHS := include
LIBRARY_PATHS = lib

LIBRARIES   := -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image  #Don't forget that -l is the option
EXECUTABLE  := main

.PHONY: clean all

all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

run: clean all
    
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $^ -o $@ -I$(INCLUDE_PATHS) -L$(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LIBRARIES)

#   Basically this is what we are doing.
#   g++ src/main.cpp -o main -Iinclude -Llib -lSDL2-2.0.0

clean:
    -rm $(BIN)/*
```

Actually, you can just run `make` and it will be done, but for simplicity, you can make a `task.json` file like this and run it with the `cmd + shift + b` shorcut:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make run",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        }
    ]
}
```

And for debugging here is the `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

That must solve the problem.

If you're having a problem with the window showing, I let you what [helped me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469534/sdl-window-not-displayed-in-windowed-mode-in-macos/48490678)

References:

https://medium.com/@edkins.sarah/set-up-sdl2-on-your-mac-without-xcode-6b0c33b723f7

https://dev.to/talhabalaj/setup-visual-studio-code-for-multi-file-c-projects-1jpi