# How to build a SDL2 project written in C++ with a makefile (mac)?

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, sdl-2

I've been trying to get a simple SDL2 project to build on Mac. I found a makefile on a different post ([SDL2 not being built on VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103312/sdl2-not-being-built-on-vs-code/)) but when I try to use it it gives me the same error I had originally.

Here is the makefile:

```
CXX       := g++
CXX_FLAGS := -std=c++2a -ggdb

BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE_PATHS := /usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.16/include
LIBRARY_PATHS = /usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.16/lib

LIBRARIES   := -lSDL2 
EXECUTABLE  := main

.PHONY: clean all

all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

run: clean all

    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*.cpp

    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $^ -o $@ -I$(INCLUDE_PATHS) -L$(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(LIBRARIES)

clean:

    -rm $(BIN)/*
```

The simple SDL2 code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    cout << "not working" << endl;
  else
    cout << "working" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And finally, here is the error:

```
g++     src/main.cpp   -o src/main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in main-e1dd26.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [src/main] Error 1
```

I'm on the mac operating system (if that makes any difference) and I installed SDL2 through homebrew.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$(SRC)/*.cpp` is illegal in that location. Try `$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)`.

Comment: Looking in the archive downloaded from SDL homepage the libraries are in separate directories for x86 and x64. Maybe you need to add that to LIBRARY_PATH? E.g. `LIBRARY_PATHS = /usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.16/lib/x64`

Comment: The command printed by make (`g++ src/main.cpp -o src/main`) clearly shows that make did not use the rule from your Makefile. Else you would have seen (`g++ -std=c++2a -ggdb ...`). So most options are missing here, reason why the linker fails because it did not find the `_SDL_Init` symbol (missing `-lSDL2`). How do you call make?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, I called make by typing "make src/main". I looked for a way to use that specific makefile but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @TobyDev To use a specific makefile type `make -f <the-makefile> src/main`. But the goal should not be `src/main`. It should be `bin/main` or `all`, as you wish. Look again at your Makefile and you'll understand why `make src/main` dose not use your own recipe but the make implicit rule (which is different because you don't use the standard make variables `CPPFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`, `LDLIBS`...)

Comment: @TobyDev Generally speaking, when asking for help about an undesired behaviour, it is always better to provide all the relevant information. In your case that is the Makefile, of course, but also the exact command you type, where you call it from, what is the files and directories layout, the complete error messages you get, etc. Would you have explained that you typed `make src/main` you would have received the correct answer almost immediately.